# How to convert AggregatedFullHttpRequest to ByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty HexDumpProxyBackendHandler example as base for my proxy. My pipeline:

```
new HttpRequestDecoder(),
new HttpContentDecompressor(),
new HttpContentCompressor(),
new HttpObjectAggregator(65536),
new ProxyFrontendHandler()
```

In `ProxyFrontendHandler` I'm trying to modify `HttpRequest` object before send it to backend server.
So, I've got `AggregatedFullHttpRequest` object in channelRead method and using `EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestEncoder())` to convert it to `ByteBuf`, but this doesn't work. For POST request it generates  http request with empty body, only headers. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Did this issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I got the content when POST in `ProxyFrontendHandler`:

```
@Override 
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
        FullHttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf content = req.getContent(); // this way?
}
```

Comment: Yes. We can get content like this. But we should then convert our FullHttpRequest to ByteBuf. And the question was how to convert it ?